# Using torch to plot neural network as a function

Tags: matplotlib, neural-network, pytorch

I've built and trained a neural network using `pytorch`, which is to be used as a numerical simulation of a function.

It is now viewed as a function of 3 variables:

- `t` as time in the 1-dim euclidean space;
- `x` as location in the 3-dim euclidean space;
- `v` as velocity in the 3-dim euclidean space.

I want to plot this function with `x` and `v` fixed as a function of `t`. Can anyone help me with an idea or some code? I'll be much obliged.